# What is the exact alternative to using `AES_set_encrypt_key` in OpenSSL 3x?

Tags: c, openssl

I am using `AES_set_encrypt_key` in my function `setkey` right now:

```
int setkey(const unsigned char *key, const int bitlength, AES_KEY *expandedKey) {
  
return AES_set_encrypt_key(key, bitlength, expandedKey); 

}
```

`AES_set_encrypt_key` is deprecated in OpenSSL3.x :

`warning: 'AES_set_encrypt_key' is deprecated: Since OpenSSL 3.0`

To resolve the deprecation warnings, after reading the [migration guide](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man7/migration_guide.html#Deprecated-low-level-encryption-functions) , I think I have to use the `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_key_length` function instead of `AES_set_encrypt_key`.

What is the exact alternate or workaround for `AES_set_encrypt_key` in OpenSSL 3x to expand the cipher key into the encryption key schedule and resolve the deprecation warning?

Comment: There's no replacement for `AES_set_encrypt_key` as such because with 'high-level' EVP you don't manage (or even declare) `AES_KEY` yourself. Instead replace `AES_encrypt` with `EVP_Encrypt{Init_ex[2],Update,Final_ex}` -- or `EVP_Cipher{same}` with enc=1 -- in either case with (first) Init call specifying an EVP_CIPHER that defines the keylength, and (optionally separate) Init call specifying the key value. The second example on the man page shows one way of using `EVP_Cipher*` for AES encrypt _or_ decrypt.